# Is there is any way to identify where the API request comes from

Tags: laravel, api, flutter, rest, laravel-api

I'm working on the Flutter app which is using APIs to get the data from the server. The flutter app is public and anyone can use without login to the application. And all working fine.

My question: is there is any way to identify where the API request comes from. Because anyone can use this API to get data and this may lead flooding the server.

If it is possible to find out from where the request is coming from, then I can process the request that is ONLY from my Flutter application.

Is it possible?

Comment: If you only want to process calls from your own service, set up authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Use https as protocol and add an api key and client secret to your app.

Then protect your api with e.g. http basic auth or OAuth.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#stateless-http-basic-authentication

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport

Comment: here we are not checking whether the request is coming from flutter app or from other scripts... the above solution will not check that right ? The above solution will work for both request from Flutter app or other source

Comment: other clients won't know your secret api key and client secret, so you can filter

Answer (score 0):

when the first request comes in to the server, issue a token, for example
(psuedo code)

```
//here stringContainingData can be a json string having details about the client and the connection
token = MyHashingFunctionUsingAPassword(stringContainingData,MyStrongPassword);
```

after sending back the token, next api access should contain the token with every request if not reject, if the token exists, do this

```
stringContainingData = MyDeHashingFunction(token,MyStrongPassword)
//verify data
mappedToken = stringToMap(stringContainingData);
if(mappedToken.containsKey('keyThatShouldBePresent') //acknowledge request
else //reject request
```

to reject further flooding, set max requests/second from a single IP

Comment: here we are not checking from where the first request comes from... if the first request comes from other than my flutter app, also will work

Comment: even the google designed api's doesn't know where the first requests comes from!!, you have to rely on authentication or else cap the requests from a IP